# Change order of configurable options programatically

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, configurable-product

I have several products like the one depicted below. We want shelf finish to be the first choice and load capacity to be the second one. I understand this can be changed in the admin panel however I have well over 300 products like this and manually changing every single product would take days.

**Does anyone have a programmatic solution (PHP or SQL) to flip these choices?**

[image: Configurable product options incorrect]

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question as I figured it out after poking around the database a bit. Your SQL query should look something like this:
Update `catalog_product_super_attribute` as a, `catalog_product_super_attribute` as b
SET a.`position` = 2, b.`position` = 1
WHERE a.attribute_id = "second_attribute_id" and b.attribute_id = "first_attribute_id";

That should do the trick